# How should I interpret time data containing information of different time lengths?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I have a question on how I should handle my data statistically.
I have made a fake dataset that's models my situation.

I have 3 time points on which I measure my dependent variable. In between these time points, I perform either:

- no manipulation
- manipulation 1
- manipulation 2
- both manipulations

between my subjects. This means I have 4 groups.
These manipulations are however given at specific timepoints in the design and are NOT balanced over time, meaning, I always start either with manipulation 1 or not at all. I never start with manipulation 2.

A timeline of the study would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrbMl.png)

Here's an example of the data:

```
head(dataframe)
        ID  Gender  Man1    Man2    Time1   Time2   Time3
         1      F      1      0        23      25      22
         2      F      1      1        12      17      19
         3      F      0      1        25      23      25
         4      M      0      0        21      26      24
         5      F      1      1        27      29      24
```

I first thought of running a mixed ANOVA on time and all four groups to see if there are any group differences. However, I was wondering if interpretating the group differences are valid. 
If I for example would get a group difference at time point 3, between the groups that got manipulation 1 vs. those that got manipulation 2, the timing wouldn't be equal. I should therefore perhaps best compare manipulation 1 by only looking at timepoint 1-2 and manipulation 2 by looking at timepoint 2-3. However, how do I compare these results with the combination of both?

I hope I made some sense here. Perhaps the answer to the question is that the study design is just not optimal :) Would love to hear some input or suggestions though!

Comment: What do you mean with: I never start with manipulation 2? Isn't that the case in line 3? Wouldn't never starting with 2 imply that you never only do manipulation 2?

Comment: The question is not completely clear.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. The timing is always according to the timeline I painted. Manipulation 1 is always first. It can however also be a sham condition. This is the case in line 3. So in this line, I could check for the main effect of manipulation 2 since this person never had manipulation 1. But this person only got this manipulation later in time. Maybe I shouldn't have used the term "Time", but "Order" might be more clear?